# How can I track pointer pressed for AdControl?

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, ads

How can I track event `PointerPressed` for AdControl? As I know AdControl supports only 3 events: `OnAdError`, `OnAdRefresh` & `OnAdEngagedChanged`.

I tried to add control on top of AdControl or add handler `(adControl.AddHandler(UIElement.PointerPressedEvent, new  PointerEventHandler(UIElement_OnPointerPressed), true))`

But it doesn't work, does anyone have an answer? And how can I simulate the click on this AdControl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event `IsEngagedChanged` is the one that is fired when the control is clicked, according to MSDN documentation :

C# : IsEngagedChanged : Raised when the user clicks the ad, and is interacting with it rather than the app.

The property `IsEngaged`, however, Gets a value that indicates whether the user is interacting with an ad.

Here's the full documentation :

[API Reference - Ad SDK Windows 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-windows-sdk-api-reference%28v=msads.10%29.aspx)

[AdControl Class - Windows 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-windows-sdk-api-reference-adcontrol%28v=msads.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Is far as my testing goes, IsEngagedChanged is only fired when dealing with ads that can go fullscreen. In other words, it will fire when a user presses your ad and it goes into fullscreen mode. The event however doesn't seem to fire again when the user leaves fullscreen mode (bug?). In "normal" ads this event doesn't seem to get fired at all.